# Condition for $C(x)=C(x^k)$ (centralizer of $x$ = centralizer of $x^k$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and $C(x) = \{ \, g \in G \mid xg=gx \} $ be the centralizer of $x \in G$. 
Let $k$ be an integer. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for $C(x)=C(x^k)$ ?

---

It is easy to notice that $C(x) \subset C(x^k)$. 
Moreover, if $( k , ord(x) )=1$, then it is clear that $C(x^k) \subset C(x)$. In this case, we will have that $C(x)=C(x^k)$. Although it is sufficient, I don't think $( k , ord(x) )=1$ is necessary.

Comment: If the group is Abelian ....

Answer (score 1):

There are no general conditions. For example, take $x$ to have order $p$. In this case, $C_G(x)=C_G(x^p)$ if and only if $x$ is central. So if $G$ is abelian this always holds, if $G=S_3$ for example, this never holds.

Whether every element that centralizes $g^2$ (say) centralizes $g$ is occasionally an important question when working with specific groups.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is:

$C_G(x)=C_G(x^k)\Leftrightarrow x\in Z(\langle x, C_G(x^k)\rangle)$

Comment: Since $x$ commutes with $x^k$ you don't need the $x$ in the generating set. Then this is pretty much the best answer.